# Install silverlight application on button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, silverlight

I am looking for a solution to install Silver light application in to user system, if he click on (install button ) in web browser.

I know how to do Out of browser but here requirement is not right click and install , it needs to install from HTML5 web page button click event.

I know can achieve from Silver light button click but I want to achieve this from HTML5 button Click event

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions && System.Windows.Interop.ComAutomationFactory.IsAvailable)
    {
        string run = "\"%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Silverlight\\sllauncher.exe\" /emulate:Silverface.xap /origin:\"http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/apps/facebookclient/ClientBin/Silverface.xap\" /overwrite";
        dynamic cmd = ComAutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
        cmd.Run(run, 1, true);
    }
}
```

Thanks,

ineffablep

Answer (score 0):

If your silverligt application is loaded on page, you may call silverlight's install method from javascript.

[Walkthrough: Calling Managed Code from JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer , to handle this I need to use HTA  File
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/How-to-distribute-a-Silverlight-OOB-Application.aspx